# How to Resize Image while Uploading using Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using  Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http for uploading Images. I need to set maximum size of uploading images to 300*300.Is there any solutions in Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http class.Please help me.Already browse for solution; but nothing helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is making with help of Zend_Filter_ImageSize.

```
$filter = new Zend_Filter_ImageSize(); 
$output = $filter->setHeight(100) 
->setWidth(200) 
->filter('./orig.jpg');
```

Comment: Uhm, Zend_Filter_ImageSize is not part of the standard Zend_Filter API, is it? At least in ZF 1.10. I couldn´t find its class definition.

Comment: You're right. You can find the code on Github http://github.com/polycaster/Zend_Filter_ImageSize

Comment: Yes. It is `polycaster's` extension. http://github.com/polycaster/Zend_Filter_ImageSize/tree/master/Zend/Filter/

Comment: +1 thanks for the link, I can use that filter implementation, too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow a bigger upload but resize, see http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/